# Setting a C#/IIS session in an Iframe works for in one parent site, but not another

Tags: c#, iis, cors

Good morning,

I've inherited this environment and I'm concerned about security issues, so I'm going to use fake urls.

My client has a wordpress website: **site1.org** and a C#/IIS application (currently framework 4.5): **app.org**. They have a new website in development **newsite.org**.

**app.org** has a custom login script that sets a session and forwards to a homepage

```
Session[UtilityFunction.Session.SessionConstants.USERNAME] = obj.UserName;
Session[UtilityFunction.Session.SessionConstants.USERID] = obj.UserProfileId;
Session[UtilityFunction.Session.SessionConstants.FIRSTNAME] = obj.FirstName;
return RedirectToAction("LoginAccountHome", "Home");
```

The pages behind the login have a check of the session in a custom attribute:

```
public class SessionTimeoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Check if the session is available and redirect to login if session not available
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filterContext">Action Executing Context</param>
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session[PLTMain.UtilityFunction.Session.SessionConstants.USERID] == null)
            {
                string redirectTo = "~/Account/Login";
                redirectTo = string.Format("~/Account/Login?returnUrl={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl));
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(redirectTo);
                return;
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Currently, **site1.org** has an iframe that surfaces **app.org**. It works fine and a Session is set.

```
<iframe id="iframe" class="login-page" src="https://app.org/main" style="width: 100%; border: none; height: 816px; display: inline-block;"></iframe>
```

When trying to surface this on **newsite.org**, the Session does not get set and you get looped back to the login page. This also occurs the same in a local html file I'm using to isolate this issue.

Is this type offer up a large security hole? I imagine it does because it works in Firefox but not in Chrome based browsers.

Other than that, I was wondering if there is anything else I can try.

### Thanks!

Things I've tried:

**1. I tried in different browsers:**
Works in Firefox, but not in Chrome/Edge. It looks like Chromium browsers have a bit more security at this time when it comes to this.

**2. I looked through code to see if there were any IP based or referrer based rules:**
The code goes directly from one piece of code to the other with nothing else in between that looks relevant.

**3. I tried a number of "fixes" including playing with CORS and sessionState in the web.config**
I tried adding

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

and

```
<sessionState cookieSameSite="None"/>
```

**4. I tried adding a CORS header to the IIS Website in the response headers**

Comment: When you access a C#/IIS application from a different domain, the browser treats it as a cross-domain request. So the session cookie is not sent with the request, causing a loop back to the login page. I've seen similar issues and the solution others have given is to implement Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) on the server side of the application, which allows controlled access to resources from different domains.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried to implement CORS both in the web.config and in the IIS server and for both "*" and "site1.org". I also added:
if (Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null)
            {
                var sessionCookie = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value);
                sessionCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                sessionCookie.Secure = true;
                Response.Cookies.Set(sessionCookie);
            }
to my global.asax.cs file, which allows things to work locally, but not on the server.

Comment: We are going to try to get a dev site on a site1.org subdomain and see if that works. 
Thanks for looking!

Comment: Is your problem solved? Any progress on this issue?